# .NET Core Dependency Injection in a Unit Test - An Interface With Multiple Concrete Implementations - Func<string, IInterface>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, dependency-injection, moq

I need your help to get the unit test method to work with Moq in a .net Core console app.
Apology, if this was asked, but I tried and couldn't find an answer.

Have three classes that implements one Interface

```
public class MailNotification : ISendNotification
{
    public bool SendNotification()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class EmailNotification : ISendNotification
{
    public bool SendNotification()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class SmsNotification : ISendNotification
{
    public bool SendNotification()
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

In the Program.cs file we have this:

```
        private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        var config = LoadConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton(config);

        services.AddTransient<IUser, User>();
        services.AddTransient<Something>();
        services.AddTransient<MailNotification>();
        services.AddTransient<EmailNotification>();
        services.AddTransient<SmsNotification>();

        //multiply concrete implementation of an Interface
        services.AddTransient<Func<string, ISendNotification>>(serviceProvider => key =>
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "Mail":
                    return serviceProvider.GetService<MailNotification>();
                case "Email":
                    return serviceProvider.GetService<EmailNotification>();
                default:
                    return serviceProvider.GetService<SmsNotification>();
            }
        });

        return services;
    }
```

Something class looks like this:

```
    public class Something
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;
    private readonly IUser user;
    private readonly Func<string, ISendNotification> sendMsg;

    public Something(IConfiguration config, IUser user, Func<string, ISendNotification>  send)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.user = user;
        this.sendMsg = send;
    }

    public bool ProcessUser()
    {
        bool result;
        switch (user.PreferredCommunication.ToString())
        {
            case "Mail":
                  result = sendMsg(NotificationType.Mail.ToString()).SendNotification();
                break;
            case "Email":
                  result = sendMsg(NotificationType.Email.ToString()).SendNotification();
                break;

            default:
                result = sendMsg (NotificationType.SMS.ToString()).SendNotification();
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the Unit test class

```
    public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper outPutHelper;
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public UnitTest1(ITestOutputHelper helper)
    {
        this.outPutHelper = helper;
        //get path to appsettings file, assembly location
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        string projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(projectPath).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

    }
    [Fact]
    [Trait("Category", "Unit")]
    public void ProcessUser_MailNotification_True()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<ISendNotification> mockNotify = new Mock<ISendNotification>();
        mockNotify.Setup(x => x.SendNotification()).Returns(true);
        Mock<IUser> mockUser = new Mock<IUser>();
        mockUser.Setup(x => x.TruncateName(It.IsAny<string>()));

        Func<string, ISendNotification> func = () => {
            return new Mock<"Mail", ISendNotification>();
        }; //< -- help help here 
           //The error is Delegate'Func<string, ISendNotification>' does not take 0 arguments

        //Act
        var sut = new Something(config, mockUser.Object, mockNotify.Object); //< -- help help here 
        //The error is Arugment 3: cannot convert from 'ISendNotification' to System.Func<string, ISendNotification>'
    }
}
```

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Would you say that your question title _"summarizes the specific problem"_? To me it only gives tangential information about what your question is about. I'm actually struggling to find the question here overall. Can you clarify what you actually need help with?

Comment: @Llama, sorry about the confusion. Guess it was difficult to say what was needed other than 'have the unit test compiled and step into the method under test', but I knew the gist of it. Thanks to Nkosi, he figured the declare for the delegated was incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: I just realised that you'd included error details in your code. I didn't see that before when I skimmed your question. I'm glad Nkosi saw it and could help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate is not being declared correctly

```
//...

Func<string, ISendNotification> send = (string key) => mockNotify.Object;

//...
```

And the delegate is also what needs to be passed to the subject under test

```
//...

var sut = new Something(config, mockUser.Object, send);

//...
```

From there the test can be exercised to assert the expected behavior

```
//...

//Act
bool actual = sut.ProcessUser();

//Assert - FluentAssertions
actual.Should().BeTrue();
```

But based on the dependency used within the member under test,

```
//...

switch (user.PreferredCommunication.ToString())

//...
```

A further setup would be needed to allow the member under test to flow to completion. But since that detail was not provided in the original question,  I wont be able to specify what that value should be.